# Difference between private npm repository and private npm registry

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I hear people talking about private npm repository and private npm registry. I wonder what is the difference between the two? Also is private npm repository same as local npm repository? Is local npm repository same as the local node_modules folder? What is stored in the private npm repository/registry? The actual code, or just references where to get them?

I read that one could host his own npm registry, that will continuously replicate itself according to the official npm registry: [npm-registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry#can-i-run-my-own-private-registry). But that cannot mean that the npm-registry itself would contain sources for all application, otherwise it would be way too big for everyone to just host by themselves? So it has to be some kind of info database that tells where to download the actual package etc?